# Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, angular-promise

I know that this error appears in questions a lot but despite my efforts I didn't manage to solve my problem.

I have a Service that fetches some categories from Parse. This is done successfully when running my test but I am getting the error shown in the title.

My code is the following:

**ParseService.js**

```
angular.module('starter').service('ParseService', ['$q', function ($q) {

  this.getAllCategories = function() {

    var deferred = $q.defer();

    var categories = [];

    var query = new Parse.Query("Category");

    query.find({

      success: function(results) {

        console.log('Succesfully queried Parse.');

        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          var result = results[i];
          categories.push(result.get("name"));
        }

        deferred.resolve(categories);

        console.log(categories);
      },

      error: function(error) {

        console.log('Error querying Parse.');

        console.log(error);

        deferred.reject(error);
      }

    });

    return deferred.promise;

  };

}]);
```

**ParseServiceTest.js**

```
describe('ParseService', function(){

  var service;

  beforeEach(function(){
    module('starter');
  });

  it ('should fetch Categories', function(done){

    beforeEach(inject(function(ParseService){
      service=ParseService;
    }));

    var promise = service.getAllCategories();

    promise.then(function(categories){
      expect(categories.length).toEqual(5);
      done();
    });

  });

});
```

Now the console output is the following:

```
'Succesfully queried Parse.'
['Pets', 'Automobile', 'Social', 'Retail', 'Technology']

Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

It seems like the service returns the categories successfully but the done() method is never executed for some reason.

You can ignore the fact that I don't mock the call to Parse. I am aware that this is not the best practice.

Answer (score 1):

For resolving/rejecting $q promises in tests, you need to start the digest cycle.

```
describe('ParseService', function() {
  var service;
  var $rootScope;

  beforeEach(module('starter'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(ParseService, _$rootScope_) {
    service = ParseService;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  it('should fetch Categories', function(done) {
    var promise = service.getAllCategories();

    promise.then(function(categories) {
      expect(categories.length).toEqual(5);
      done();
    });
    // run digest cycle to resolve $q promises
    $rootScope.$digest();
  });
});
```